# How to display input field if select value is null in php

Tags: php, sql

How can I display that when select value is null I want to display input field to enter customer own choice. I am new to php so anyone can please suggest me how to do it? Here is my reference code.

```
<select class="form-control" name="outlet">
<option>Select Outlet</option>
<?php 
$values = explode(",",$camp_outlet);
foreach(explode(",",$camp_outlet) as $value){
?>
<option value="<?php echo "$value";?>">
<?php echo "$value";?>
</option>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: so are there any null values in `$camp_outlet`? or do you mean if the user doesn't want to select any options from `$camp_outlet`, then they should get an input field to type in whatever they want?

Comment: If there are no values from `$camp_outlet` then only they can input their choice . if there are values in `$camp_outlet` they have to select one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php 
        $theData = explode(",",$camp_outlet);
        if (count($theData) > 0 ){
            echo "<select class=\"form-control\" name=\"outlet\">";
            echo "<option>Select Outlet</option>";

            foreach($theData as $value){ // loop through the data and add the options to the select input
                echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
            }

            echo "</select>";
         } else {
             echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"outlet\">";
         }
     ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your help its working fine after i changed the  value `(count($theData) > 1 ){`